# Set Process Variable Without Calling Process.Start

Tags: c#, process

I want to set a Process variable without using "Process.Start("procName")" in
`Process myProcess = Process.Start("procName");`
Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Set a variable in the process that is to be started? Or set a variable on the instance of `Process`? Also, what is the reason for not using `Process.Start("procName")`?

Comment: See below, I've explained there.

Answer (score 1):

This will construct a new instance of the `Process` class. But a more interesting question might be, why would you want to do this?

```
var proc = new Process();
```

Comment: I made a Skyrim launcher which launches ENB Injector and SKSE. The issue was I wanted to detect when the game closed so ENB Injector would close but the program was detecting whether or not SKSE was open rather than the game itself.

Comment: Perhaps checking for an existing process (Skyrim) and binding to it might help. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1f692ky%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)'s an MSDN article on how to do that.

Comment: What does binding to it do? I'm pretty new to this whole C# thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.WaitForExit()` on the skyrim process. Here is an example that opens `CMD.exe` and checks if notepad is open, if it is open it will wait for notepad to close before closing `CMD.exe`
Note that if notepad is not running the `.CloseMainWindow()` fails because it comes to quick.

```
        Process cmd = Process.Start("cmd.exe");  // get ENB process

        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"); // Get "skyrim" here
        if (p.Length > 0)
        {
            p[0].WaitForExit();
        }

        cmd.CloseMainWindow();
        // or cmd.Close();
```

Comment: Tried that with Application.Exit(); after cmd.CloseMainWindow(); and my application seemed to close after skyrim launched but not the ENB process.